# How to find the elliptic curve of a window arch - Real world problem

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, conic-sections

My Aunt replaces windows for a living. She has to replace the window in the arch of a doorway, and she sent the window company [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA45e.png).

[image: diagram]

They sent back a window that has a greater curve than what was needed. How do we measure the window so that they are able to send us the right curve? In [this reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27uwN.png) the cardboard is an exact cutout of the glass, and the incorrectly sized window they sent is underneath.

[image: reference image]

Do we need to measure from the bottom left corner to the center of the curve and send them that measurement? How do we find the center of the curve?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> In practice the easiest thing is probably to provide the glass cutter with a cardboard template. Mathematically speaking, we need to know whether the curve is an arc of a circle, or some other curve such as an ellipse (or a parabola, or some freehand arc...).

Comment: Any answer you get here will depend on assuming a model for the arc of the glass plane which is unknown (the actual arc may differ from that of a mathematical ellipse). So I would second the idea of sending the vendor the cardboard template.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang That sounds like an excellent idea. I believe the curve they have sent has an arc of a circle (which was incorrect), and that it actually was supposed to be an ellipse. I highly doubt it's freehand since the window is made by some sort of machine.

My Aunt says sending the template probably won't work as they need to be able to create both glass AND a frame, I asked her if sending two templates will work.

Comment: @GaretWebster You can always measure points on your template and plot the points to see if they indeed follow an ellipse. I think measuring points on your template and creating a model this way would be the best path forward for you if sending the template wont work.

Answer (score 3):

Let us follow your title by assuming that the shape is an arc of an ellipse with horizontal and vertical axes intersecting at the bottom right of the figure. Let us work with the implicit equation

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\tag{1}$$

where $b$ is known: $b=28 \tfrac34 = 28.75$ and $a$ is determined by the fact that if $x=32 \tfrac38 = 32.375$ then $y=9 \tfrac58 = 9.625$ giving the following constraint for $a$ :

$$\frac{32.375^2}{a^2}+\frac{9.625^2}{28.75^2}=1$$

yielding $a=34.3576$.

Now you have all the elements for plotting the corresponding curve, in particular by turning (1) into the explicit form for the quadrant of interest for you:

$$y=b \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$$